# which are diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

a) Unitary matrices are normal matrix hence  diagonalizable as a consequence of spectral theorem

b)same as a)

c)No idea.but I think it may not be diagonalizable unless it has one eigen value with dimension of eigen space $1$

d) No idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The [shear matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_matrix) $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$$ has two real eigenvalues (both equal $1$) complex entries, and cannot be diagonalized.

Comment: thanku, could you just confirm me am I right in a,b,c?

Comment: @Kuttus: $a$ and $b$ are correct.

Comment: what is strictly upper triangular matrix?

Comment: @Kuttus: Not sure.  I assumed it just meant upper triangular.

Comment: do you know the answer of $c$? I am thinking still though

Comment: @Kuttus A matrix is called *strictly upper triangular* if it is upper triangular and its main diagonal is zero.